# Is this 'there' a deictic or does it mean 'at that point'?

Tags: vocabulary

> He turned back to Harry. "You'll soon find out some wizarding families
>   are much better than others, Potter. You don't want to go making
>   friends with the wrong sort. I can help you **there**." 
>   He held
>   out his hand to shake Harry's, but Harry didn't take it. 
>   "I
>   think I can tell who the wrong sort are for myself, thanks," he said
>   coolly.  
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘there’ a deictic indicating Hogwarts school where they’re going now, or does it have an adverbial meaning ‘at that point’?

Comment: Kiam got it; but I might add that *deictic* just means 'pointing', so it's a deictic adverb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I can help you there." in that case means "I can help you with choosing the right friends."

Comment: Yes. Or, to preserve the spatial metaphor of *there*, "I can help you ***in*** that matter."

Comment: @StoneyB: Or to more explicitly stick to the metaphor, *"I can help you in that **area**."*